# My springBoot project can't autowire his services with the repositories

Tags: java, spring-boot, service, annotations, repository

As i said in the title i have a springboot project and i'm trying to run it, but when i try to start a clean install using maven i get an error during the test :

> `Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.805 s <<< FAILURE! - in ---myprojectpath---`
> `contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!`
> `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`
> `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'myService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'myRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type '---myprojectpath---' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`
> `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'myRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type '---myprojectpath---' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`
> `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type '---myprojectpath---' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

if i ignore this error during the build of mav`your text`en i still get a different error when i try tu run my app, i hope that resolving this error ill' be finally able to solve everything.

Anyways here is a part of  my controller:

```
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/Mycontroller")
    public class Mycontroller{
        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Mycontroller.class);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        @Autowired
        private MyService MyService ;
    
        @GetMapping(value = "/getDatas", produces = "application/json")
        public ResponseEntity getDatas() {
            try {
                DataList responseEntity = new DataList ();
                List<Data> datas= MyService.getDatasBean();
                ..........
    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ..........
            }
    
        }
    }
```

here is my service:

```
    public interface MyService {
    
        List<Data> getDatasBean() throws Exception;
    }
```

here is the implementation of my service

```
    import org.slf4j.Logger;import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
    import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
    import java.util.List;
    
    @Service
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService{
        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyServiceImpl.class);
    
        @Autowired
        private MyRepository MyRepository ;
    
        public List<Data> getDatasBean() throws Exception {
            LOGGER.info(String.format("looking for datas"));
            try {
                return MyRepository.getAllDatas();
            } catch (NoResultException e) {
                return null;
            } catch (IllegalStateException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
                throw new Exception(e);
                //throw new BackOfficeEntityException(String.format("error"), e);
            }
        }
    }
```

here is the repository:

```
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
    import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    @Repository
    public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<Data, Long> {
        @Query("SELECT a " +"FROM Data a ")
        List<Data> getAllDatas();
    }
```

as you can read in the log the error is when i bind Myserviceimpl with MyRepository... but i don't understand what i did wrong.... here is my pom.xml:

```
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven 4.0.0.xsd">
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        
            <parent>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.1</version>
                <relativePath/>
                <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
            </parent>
        
            <artifactId>Myproject-jpa</artifactId>
            <packaging>jar</packaging>
            <name>Myproject-jpa</name>
        
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12.4</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
        
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <version>5.3.14</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        
            <build>
                <plugins>
        
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.6.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>11</source>
                            <target>11</target>
                            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                                <path>
                                    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
                                </path>
                            </annotationProcessorPaths>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </project>
```

any help is appreciated, thanks :)

I tried to run the various maven steps (clean,validate,compile,test,package,verify,install) but i got the error that i already pasted, and i tryed to run anyway my application but i get a different error(i think that this last error can be resolvedjust resolving the error that comes up during the test).
i tryed to change the dependencies in the pom.xml but honestly i still don't understand it at all.

Comment: Can you provide the reference of '---myprojectpath---' ?
Looks like there is reference of ---myprojectpath--- somewhere in your MyRepository

Answer (score 0):

No major mistakes in your code. Just use the naming standards(camelCase) properly for your objects. Here is the working code with the proper naming of variables.

**MyServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository ;

    public List<Data> getDatasBean() throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info(String.format("looking for datas"));
        try {
            return myRepository.getAllDatas();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        } catch (IllegalStateException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
            //throw new BackOfficeEntityException(String.format("error"), e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Mycontroller.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Mycontroller")
public class Mycontroller{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Mycontroller.class);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService ;

    @GetMapping(value = "/getDatas", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity getDatas() {
        try {
            List responseEntity = new ArrayList();
            List<Data> datas= myService.getDatasBean();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        ..........
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but even changing the object's names i still see the same error log, maybe there is something wrong in the pom.xml?